# Shared folder belongs to root in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, permissions, kali-linux, gnome, virtualbox

I have a Kali Linux guest running on a Windows 10 20H2 host, and I have a shared folder on the guest which is only accessible by root, which I prefer not to use for everyday tasks. Most websites say to run the usermod command to add my user to *vboxsf*, but even if I run the command as root, it doesn't do anything, even after multiple restarts. I have VirtualBox Guest Additions installed on the guest, but no matter what I do, I can't get permission. I even tried launching Nautilus as root and trying to change the permissions from a GUI, but it reverts back to the original settings before I click the save button. Please help!

Comment: Why do you not change the permission within Kali and your own linux-startup-script?

Comment: I did try that, but it didn't work.